# hooking post-run downloaded dex files

Tags: android, frida

Firstly sorry if the terminology of any of the below is incorrect. I'm new to the Frida/android investigation game and mostly just doing it to improve my understanding at the moment.

I have an APK which I am analysing. I can see through the usual decompilation that certain aspects are obfuscated, others appear to be encrypted and calls appear to disappear into nothing. After analysing the traffic through hooking the crypto libraries I can see it downloads a file starting PK.

To investigate further I've write the zip to disk and extracted it. Inside is a classes.dex file that I believe contains some of the hidden content I've been searching for to close the gaps I keep finding.

Unfortunately, that is where this is currently ending. I can see the new functions and classes but when I try to hook them for manipulation (bypassing emulator detection is a key thing in there) Frida complains as the function/class doesn't exist from the outset. It appears to me that these classes are imported somehow while running, post startup.

What I am looking at doing next is to intercept the download, replacing it with a dex file I modify as required which should then allow me to continue with my analysis but I wondered if there was any easier way? Is it possible to target these classes that are not loaded immediately, and if so can someone point me in the direction I need to look to investigate how? I am presuming that there is a built in android function that needs to do this import I could look for, but I'm unsure where to start.

Any help/direction/guidance would be appreciated. To confirm, I'm wondering if the below flow is possible:

1. Start the application, hooking crypto libraries
2. Wait for the new classes.dex file to be downloaded
3. Hook into these classes on loading
4. Automagically bypass the newly loaded classes

Thanks.

Comment: How will you intercept the download?

Comment: I have one of two ideas. Either take over the class java.io.FileOutputStream and look for the file to be written or use the crypto libraries and modify the output data as it streams through.

Comment: I would start hooking the common methods and classes for loading DEX code at run-time like `DexClassLoader`. Hooking the file download can be very hard as there are dozen of way to download a file. In difference to that the number of ways to load DEX code is very limited and therefore easier to hook. At that time you can still stop the app, get the DEX file to be loaded, modify/replace it and then continue code loading.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'll start there.